# MYSQL select * plus one column again

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Some SQL toolsets like PDO can do special things based on the first column selected, such as take it as class name to instantiate or to use it as key into a hashtable. Unfortunately PDO removes that column from the result. What if I still want it to be part of the result?

I've tried queries such as

```
SELECT `class` as `myclass`, * FROM `mytable`
```

but I'm getting errors:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `mytable` at line 1

I understand that there can't be conflicts in column names, hence the

```
as `myclass`
```

And the following works just fine:

```
SELECT `class` as `myclass`, `class` FROM `mytable`
```

Is this possible at all without doing a self-join or putting the full list of columns?

Comment: Did you try mytable.* ? That might resolve your error.

Comment: Don't use evil `SELECT *`. I'd be tempted to find a toolset that didn't remove the column - but if writing out the column names longhand solves the problem, then that seems like a reasonable approach

Comment: @NigelRen the suggested duplicate is for oracle, not for mysql.

Comment: Although the answer was for Oracle, the solution is the same - `select rownum, table.* from table` (from previously linked answer)

Comment: Thank you @NigelRen for pointing out the possible duplicate. It didn't come up in my searches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do like below

```
SELECT `mytable`.`class` as `myclass`, `mytable`.*  FROM `mytable`
```

or like this

```
SELECT t.class AS myclass, t.*  FROM mytable t;
```

Comment: Wow, all three solutions work in terms of MySQL syntax errors.
The first one doesn't help me much because again I can't control what will be the first column selected.
The 3rd solution is best, because I can use a generic table alias which will be the smallest modification to my query builder.